# Is it possible to have both v4 and v7 in same project

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-support-library, android-recyclerview

I am getting 'can not resolve symbol' for below three

> import android.support.**v4**.view.MotionEventCompat;
>   import android.support.**v4**.view.ViewConfigurationCompat;
>   import android.support.**v7**.widget.RecyclerView;

And I have

```
compile ('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
```

in my gradle file but it still doesn't resolve

Comment: Yes it is possible. Are you sure you did a Gradle sync?

Comment: yes lot of times did not work

Comment: Maybe try putting in a version, current one is `21.0.3`, I'd recommend against using `+` so that you are aware every time you update the libraries.

Comment: thanks tried that as well, no luck :(

Comment: That's a strange one. Maybe post your whole gradle file to make sure you're putting the dependencies in the right place. Btw there should be no reason to exclude that v4 module, even if it comes with the recyclerview package it'll be the same version as the one you're including anyway. This is really only useful to prevent getting conflicting versions of the same module with third party libraries.